# How to use delay correctly in Popovers of reactstrap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I read the [Popovers' doc](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/popovers/). I tried to use `delay` on Popover, but the delay does not work.

Did I make a mistake?

<kbd>[Live version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cj6bfo)</kbd>

```
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      popoverOpen: false
    };
  }

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      popoverOpen: !this.state.popoverOpen
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
     <div>
        <Button id="Popover1" onClick={this.toggle}>
          Launch Popover
        </Button>
        <Popover delay={2000} placement="bottom" isOpen={this.state.popoverOpen} target="Popover1" toggle={this.toggle}>
          <PopoverHeader>Title</PopoverHeader>
          <PopoverBody>Body</PopoverBody>
        </Popover>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: By 'but the delay does not work' what exactly do you mean? what happens?

Comment: @RishikeshDhokare 'the delay does not work' means no delay

Comment: That looks like a legit bug: https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/blob/master/src/Popover.js#L86 it only calls show when this.props.isOpen is true, and the interesting timeout stuff only happens when show is called and this.props.isOpen is false.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative if the delay prop doesn't work you can always do this to your `toggle` func

```
toggle = () => {
 setInterval(() => {
   this.setState({ popoverOpen: !this.state.popoverOpen });
 }, 2000)   
};
```